# Windows copy command process info

Tags: windows-xp, windows-server-2008-r2, copy

Is there any specific package for `copy` command which shows the process of being copied.

In windows while using copy from command line I could not see the process but the blinking cursor and I'm wondering if there is any application that could be downloaded for free and which shows additional information that what has been copied and what are left or how many percentage it has been copied...etc. Any body using any?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ROBOCOPY` is included in Windows and displays progress information.

Comment: +1 - I use robocopy for *everything* these days

Comment: It's also worth noting that when you use the /tee option you can both see the progress and send it to a log file. Very handy for helping to find problems.

Answer (score 2):

Robocopy will work but has some quirks that can take some getting used to.  For a graphical approach try [richcopy](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/d/0/fd05def7-68a1-4f71-8546-25c359cc0842/HoffmanUtilitySpotlight2009_04.exe) It's also got some quirks but are s little mpre obscure.  When it comes down to command line or logging I use [xxcopy](http://www.xxcopy.com/) which I've found to be the fastest and most versatile copy program I've ever seen.

Comment: +1 for xxcopy and richcopy

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try `xcopy`, there are bunch of options.

Answer (score 1):

Robocopy - been using it for years for replicating directiories/backups and its the best I've come across so far. As mentioned above it has a few quirks.

I'd never heard of richcopy - just downloaded it, thanks for the link.

Ian